# Cos'è un "elmetto retato"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto la frase seguente:

> E intorno a quella zona il via vai di camionette con soldati di diverse nazionalità  con gli **elmetti retati** a pattugliare in quel Campo di Marte del 1944, 'terra di nessuno', delicato confine tra zona operativa tedesca e  alleata.

Le diverse accezioni dell'aggettivo "retato" le ho trovate sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00926.jpg). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cos'è un "elmetto retato", anche se immagino si tratti di qualche tipo di elmetto militare. Quindi, la mia domanda è: potreste spiegarmi il significato di "elmetto retato"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sono abbastanza certo che significhi che l'elmetto era [avvolto da una rete, come questo](https://www.expoarmy.com/cat/929/g-0.jpg?t=1559162334) - da quel che so la rete serve a migliorare il cammuffamento, infilando per es. delle foglie.

Comment: Ah! Ecco un sito web che parla di tali elmetti: http://www.ilcastellodimontegabbione.it/PagineWWII/Elmetti%20inglesi%20ww2%20Elementi%20costruttivi%20-%20Reti%20Camuffamenti.htm.